# Creating 10 us high, 40 us low signal from 555 timer

Tags: 555

Is it possible to create a 10 us logic high signal and 40 us low then 10 us high again with 555 timer as shown below?

[image: I wish]

I have tried to change the values of R1, R2 and C1 but that process didn’t let me have a time low longer than time high.

Comment: tH must be greater than 50% with basic 555 circuit.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat ye i figured that so how can i add a delay in this case then?

Comment: You could use 2.  First giving 50μs as a multivibrator and second as a 10μs one shot.  But 1 will not do as you want.

Comment: You can add an extra transistor for inverting the signal.

Comment: As @aconcernedcitizen says use a npn, base resistor and collector resistor to flip polarity with 80% duty cycle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not the best solution, but this can also be useful ...

R2 & R3 are the two parts of a potmeter, it adjusts the duty cycle.

[image]